# PHP removing querystring variable from a string

Tags: php, string

This is **$postfields** value:

```
image=%40E%3A%5Cdev%5Cphoto.jpg&oauth_timestamp=1291739697&oauth_token=123456&tile=true
```

I need to take out any the **image=xxxxx** part of that value so i only have this at the end:

```
oauth_timestamp=1291739697&oauth_token=123456&tile=true
```

I tried explode() and parse_str() approaches with no success. The best solution would be to find any **image=xxxxx** inside the long string, then convert it to an array like this:

```
$array['image'] = '%40E%3A%5Cdev%5Cphoto.jpg';
$array['oauth_timestamp'] = '1291739697';
$array['oauth_token'] = '123456';
$array['tile'] = 'true';
```

That way is really easy to just unset($array['image']) and then implode() everything back. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to take it apart, and [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to put it back together again.

Comment: i tried that approach also. the problem is that sometimes there are more or less variables in the querystring... and because of that http_build_query becomes really cumbersome.

Comment: ... How so? Take the array returned, remove the key, pass it back in.

Comment: but parse_str doesn't return any arrays. It only creates new variables based on the key and value of the long string http://php.net/parse_str

Comment: it would be great if parse_str would return the variable names as key names in an array.

Comment: ... I don't think we were reading the same documentation then... "arr

    If the second parameter arr is present, variables are stored in this variable as array elements instead.
"

Comment: damn... i missed that argument. That solves everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use strpos of &oauth and then use substring

```
$rest = substr($post_data, strpos($post_data, '&oauth'));
```

Comment: @thedom, hey, thanks! Sometimes simpler is better. Though I believe @Ignacio's solution is better-served and more robust.

Comment: this works only if image goes first and before &oauth... what if image goes in the middle of the querystring between yet unknown variables? (i cannot control that :s)

Comment: I'm aware of the limitations, which is why I pointed out the other solution is inevitably a better-fit, but was just posting a lightweight solution. That's the joy of SO, you get many ways to skin a cat. ;-)

Comment: hehe, i'll stay with the parse_str() approach. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function removeVarFromQueryString($varToRemove, $originalQs=null) {
    if (!$originalQs) {
        $originalQs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }

    $params = [];
    parse_str($originalQs, $params);

    unset($params[$varToRemove]);
    return http_build_query($params);
}
```

Then for your example:

```
$qs = "image=%40E%3A%5Cdev%5Cphoto.jpg&oauth_timestamp=1291739697&oauth_token=123456&tile=true";
echo removeVarFromQueryString("image", $qs); // => oauth_timestamp=1291739697&oauth_token=123456&tile=true
```